# not all OSM polygons downloading in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, topology, download

I have been trying to download all of the polygons contained within OSM for a particular extent of the city.

When I do this through > Vector > OpenStreetMap > Download Data, however, many polygons are left out.

For example, this is the result that I get:

[image]

However, when another person used downloaded data from the same extent, the result was much more complete (the green polygons are the ones that are missing from my download):

[image]

If we look at the data over an OSM map, we see that indeed those polygons that did not download for me do exist:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Try the QuickOSM plugin instead

Comment: When I use the same map extent with QuickOSM, I get "Query successful but no result"  How do I get around this issue?

Comment: what filter (search) are you using with QuickOSM, and which city is this? Have you changed the advanced options (are any of the options like way, relation, multipolygon etc unchecked?).  With QuickOSM I'd suggest the quick query, setting key to `building` and leave value empty. Or did you try that already?

Comment: Having the exact same problems (only 5 years later).